# The text selection in Firefox is still working after disabling it from CSS

Tags: css, firefox, selection

I am using the CSS rule:

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

This disables the selection of a div like the one below in Chrome but not in Firefox:

```
<div class="noselect">
    <span>This text cannot be selected</span>
</div>
```

I have the latest browser versions. A sample can be found in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUfe4/).

What is different in Firefox? How can I disable the selection there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for firefox: instead of "moz-none" just use "none" only

Answer (score 0):

Also found that `-moz-none` instead of `moz-none` also works. But yes, the `none` is even better.